# Does sympy give erroneous simplifications?

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following calculation for sympy:

```
import sympy

q, r = sympy.symbols("q r")
equation = (((-q + r) - (q - r)) <= 0).simplify()
print(equation) # q >= r

equation = ((sympy.sqrt(2) * (-q + r) - sympy.sqrt(2) * (q - r)) <= 0).simplify()
print(equation) # q <= r
```

I don't see why the results should differ. What am I missing?

## Edit

I am using version 1.5.1 of `sympy` and can see this on Python 3.6.6 and 3.7.7.

Comment: That's not what I get when I run this code.

Comment: What SymPy version are you on? I got `2*q - 2*r >= 0` and `2*sqrt(2)*(-q + r) <= 0` on SymPy 1.4.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Updated my question. I am using a later version... Did you simplify both results? Why does it not cancel the 2's and 2sqrt(2)'s?

Comment: I get the same thing as OP on the same version. It doesn't seem to do it if you multiply by `sqrt(4)` or `sqrt(16)` but it will still do with with `sqrt(5)`

Comment: Just tried it on 1.5.1. I see the same output you get. This looks like a bug.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this except with sympy 1.4. I tried this with sympy 1.4 and I get: `2*q - 2*r >= 0, 2*sqrt(2)*(-q + r) <= 0`. With sympy 1.5.1, 1.6rc2 and current master I get `q >= r, q >= r`. I tested sympy 1.5.1 with Python 2.7, 3.5, 3.7 and 3.8 and got the same results in every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this is given [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19407). It looks like `gcd` was assumed to behave like `igcd` (which gives a nonnegative value). But when dealing with non-integers, `gcd` currently can give a negative result, thus the error. So SymPy will either modify `gcd` and the simplify code will work or the simplification routine must account for the sign of the extracted `gcd`.

Comment: I opened that issue, forgot to link it :P